# Can I compile VLC with EVERY module?

Tags: vlc

I'm looking at instructions to compile VLC, and I have to say which modules I want to include.

Well, I'd like to include everything it's possible to compile with. Can I do this?

Comment: Probably being obtuse but why would you want to compile it when you can have it painlessly installed by the Software Center?

Comment: I'd like every module, and the version compiled for Ubuntu doesn't have every module enabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the output of `./configure --help`, there's no config option to enable every input/video/audio/interface etc pp plugin in a single step.

But you could restrict the output of `./configure --help` to those options that are disabled by default: `./configure --help |grep disabled`. This will return something like

```
--cache-file=FILE   cache test results in FILE [disabled]
--enable-non-utf8       support legacy non-UTF-8 systems (default disabled)
--enable-debug          build with run-time assertions (default disabled)
--enable-gprof          profile with gprof (default disabled)
--enable-cprof          profile with cprof (default disabled)
--enable-coverage       build for test coverage (default disabled)
--enable-run-as-root    allow running VLC as root (default disabled)
--enable-pvr            support PVR V4L2 cards (default disabled)
--enable-vcdx           navigate VCD with libvcdinfo (default disabled)
--enable-realrtsp       Real RTSP module (default disabled)
--enable-wma-fixed      libwma-fixed module (default disabled)
--enable-shine          shine mp3 encoding module (default disabled)
--enable-omxil          openmax il codec module (default disabled)
--enable-iomx           iomx codec module (default disabled)
--enable-merge-ffmpeg   merge FFmpeg-based plugins (default disabled)
--enable-switcher       Stream-out switcher plugin (default disabled)
--enable-faad           faad codec (default disabled)
--enable-real           Real video decoder module (default disabled)
--enable-tremor         Tremor decoder support (default disabled)
--enable-egl            OpenGL support through EGL (default disabled)
--enable-android-surface   Android Surface video output module (default disabled)
--enable-ios-vout    iOS video output module (default disabled)
--enable-directfb       DirectFB support (default disabled)
--enable-aa             aalib output (default disabled)
--enable-audioqueue     AudioQueue audio module (default disabled)
--enable-opensles       Android OpenSL ES audio module (default disabled)
--enable-hildon         Hildon touchscreen UI (default disabled)
--disable-ncurses       ncurses interface support (default disabled)
--enable-xosd           xosd interface support (default disabled)
--enable-fbosd          fbosd interface support (default disabled)
--enable-lirc           lirc support (default disabled)
--enable-update-check   update checking system (default disabled)
--enable-growl          growl notification plugin (default disabled)
--enable-media-library  media library (default disabled)
```

This list may be a good starting point to decide what to enable. Just enabling every option without checking the consequences won't be wise, the build will likely fail due to missing libs. Additionally, you should double-check if that list does cover all important options; i didn't check the full output of  `./configure --help` *en detail*.